# Plot graph using shell for total file count and date created

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, csh

I want to create a histogram with total file count intervals of 50 on Y-axis and time created in weeks on X-axis (i.e if new files were created between week 1 and 2 and so on)

Something like

200, 150, 100 , 50 files created during a certain week
7, 14, 21, 28 days on Y-axis. Kind of lost on how to implement this. Any help is appreciated

Update: I am trying along these lines

```
find <dirname> -type f -ctime -1 -ctime -7 | wc -l
find <dirname> -type f -ctime +7 -ctime -14 | wc -l
```

Find the max number and use this as my X-axis upper limit. Then divide this number into equal intervals to plot my X-axis

Comment: Draw how? In terminal with "ASCII graphs" (like https://github.com/glamp/bashplotlib), or with external tools generating a graph, like [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)?

Comment: Or do you want to write a shell script that does it directly? That would be very broad.

Comment: Draw using a shell script. Where say during week 1 I had 200 files, It will put a "X" at the intersection of 200 and 7days(1week) kind of. So I first need to find what is the maximum number of files created during a particular week, use that as my upper limit for X-axis and then divide it into 4-5 equal intervals to plot. Any easy way to do it?

Comment: Just updated the original post with what I am trying

Comment: You DO know that UNIX doesn't store file creation times so there's no way to get that info unless you record it yourself somewhere when you create the files, right? `ctime` is change time, not creation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies being ksh instead of bash (bash level is near echo "Hello World") :)...

Would that do what you need ?

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    ######################################
    #
    # statDirReport.sh
    #
    version="1.0"
    # Andre Gelinas, 2018
    #
    ######################################

    #############
    # Variables
    #############

    typeset -F2 SCALE

    # Max value of X
    X_SCALE=30


    #############
    # Main
    #############

    if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
        DIRNAME=$1
    else
        print -n "Enter full path to stat : "; read DIRNAME
    fi

    if [[ ! -d $DIRNAME || ! -r $DIRNAME || ! -x $DIRNAME ]]; then
        print "ERROR - Directory unusable - Exiting"
        exit
    fi

    ## Getting the data

    CTIME1=1
    CTIME2=0
    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
        CTIME2=$(($i*7))
        FILE_COUNT[$i]=$(find $DIRNAME -type f -ctime +$CTIME1 -ctime -$CTIME2 | wc -l)
        #To find late on the max amount
        F_COUNT[${FILE_COUNT[$i]}]=${FILE_COUNT[$i]}
        #
        CTIME1=$CTIME2
    done

    #Doing some math

    ## Highest number of file
    MAX_COUNT=${F_COUNT[-1]}
    ## Find the value of each tick
    SCALE=$(($MAX_COUNT/$X_SCALE))

    ## Find the real length of the histogram for each week
    ## having the highest amount using full x scale (integer mathematics)

    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
        DATA_2_SCALE[$i]=$(((${FILE_COUNT[$i]}*$X_SCALE)/$MAX_COUNT))
    done

    # Getting the report

    typeset -L2 Col1
    typeset -L1 Col2
    typeset -L$(($X_SCALE+5)) Col3
    typeset -L5 Col4

    Col1="Wk"
    Col2=" "
    Col3="Data"
    Col4="Real"

    clear
    print "statDirReport v$version\tScale is #=$SCALE\n"
    print "$Col1$Col2$Col3$Col4\n"
    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
        Col1=$i
        Col2="|"
        graph=""
        Col4=${FILE_COUNT[$i]}
        for ((j=1;j<=${DATA_2_SCALE[$i]};j++)); do
            graph+="#"
        done
        Col3=$graph
        print "$Col1$Col2$Col3$Col4"
    done
```

Edit to modify to add dates as title for the histograms. Modify the last part, right after the "DATA_2_SCALE" loop, with :

```
    #Setting the title of each histogram

    ## Finding how many sec since the beginning of time

    TODAY_SEC=$(date +"%s")

    ## Finding real date for find range

    SEC_PER_DAY=86400

    lastDate=$(date -u -d @"$TODAY_SEC" +"%m/%d")

    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
            firstDate=$(date -u -d @"$(($TODAY_SEC-(7*$i*$SEC_PER_DAY)))" +"%m/%d")
            WEEK[$i]=$firstDate" to "$lastDate" "
            lastDate=$firstDate
    done

    # Getting the report

    typeset -L15 Col1
    typeset -L1 Col2
    typeset -L$(($X_SCALE+5)) Col3
    typeset -L5 Col4

    Col1="Wk"
    Col2=" "
    Col3="Data"
    Col4="Real"

    clear
    print "statDirReport v$version\tScale is #=$SCALE\n"
    print "$Col1$Col2$Col3$Col4\n"
    for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
            Col1=${WEEK[$i]}
            Col2="|"
            graph=""
            Col4=${FILE_COUNT[$i]}
            for ((j=1;j<=${DATA_2_SCALE[$i]};j++)); do
                    graph+="#"
            done
            Col3=$graph
            print "$Col1$Col2$Col3$Col4"
    done
```

Comment: It generates something as below which looks great. How do I swap and make X-axis 1234 and Y-axis Real in the above code? Sort of the Col has to be Row.. Anyway to do that? Wk Data                               Real 

1 |##############################     13644
2 |########################           10968
3 |#########                          4391 
4 |####                               1903

Comment: Well, probably...but not that easy. Scripts are writing line per line. One would have to compute what each line would look that include all 4 columns at the same time. Not impossible, but may I ask why ? Screens have usually more width than height making the graph easier to see especially with bigger number.

Comment: Thanks! One of the original specs I had received had a sample output with weeks on Y-axis and No. of files on X. So was wondering if it's some small tweak. This works great though!

Comment: I have one more question: Is there a way I can represent -ctime1 -ctime +7 for instance as 06/01 to 06/07 in the table? I see printf has a "%Ar" option which gives time stamp on every file. But I just want it to create a table by basically replacing 1 to 4 in the table by the corresponding date range

Comment: Well, keep in mind that playing with date is always tricky...but I'll edit my original answer to add that request...hoping it'll do what you want.

Comment: Wow int think it required so many changes! Thanks a lot for your time! Works perfect

Answer (score 4):

This is a start using GNU awk for time functions (untested since you didn't provide concise, testable sample input that we could test against):

```
find "$1" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
awk -v RS='\0' '
BEGIN {
    nowSecs = systime()
}
{
    fileName     = gensub(/\S+\s+/,"",1)
    fileModSecs  = int($1)
    fileAgeSecs  = nowSecs - fileModSecs
    fileAgeDays  = int(fileAgeSecs / (24 * 60 * 60))
    fileAgeWeeks = int(fileAgeDays / 7)
    weekNr       = fileAgeWeeks + 1
    fileCnts[weekNr]++
    numWeeks     = (weekNr > numWeeks ? weekNr : numWeeks)
    maxFileCnt   = (fileCnts[weekNr] > maxFileCnt ? fileCnts[weekNr] : maxFileCnt)
    print nowSecs, fileModSecs, fileAgeSecs, fileAgeDays, fileAgeWeeks, weekNr, fileName | "cat>&2"
}
END {
    for (fileCnt=maxFileCnt; fileCnt>0; fileCnt--) {
        for (weekNr=1; weekNr<=numWeeks; weekNr++) {
            if (weekNr in fileCnts) {
                char[weekNr] = "*"
            }
            printf "%s%s", char[weekNr], (weekNr<numWeeks ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (weekNr=1; weekNr<=numWeeks; weekNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", weekNr, (weekNr<numWeeks ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
'
```

You need to figure out the details of the loops in the END section for printing the histogram but the above at least shows you how to get the count of files by week without calling find multiple times and hard-coding the number of days week by week.

Answer (score 3):

Using [feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot/blob/master/INSTALL) on a home directory:

```
dirname=~
e=0
for f in `seq 7 7 28` ; do 
    find "${dirname}" -type f -ctime +$e -ctime -$f | wc -l
    e=$f 
done 2> /dev/null | 
feedgnuplot  --terminal 'dumb 50,15' --with boxes --unset grid --exit
```

Output:

```
  5500 +-+-----+-------+------+-------+-----+-+   
  5000 +-+ *********   +      +       +     +-+   
  4500 +-+ *       *       ********         +-+   
  4000 +-+ *       *       *      *         +-+   
  3500 +-+ *       *       *      *         +-+   
  3000 +-+ *       *       *      *         +-+   
  2500 +-+ *       *********      *         +-+   
  2000 +-+ *       *       *      *         +-+   
  1500 +-+ *       *       *      *         +-+   
  1000 +-+ *   +   *   +   *  +   ********* +-+   
   500 +-+-********************************-+-+   
       0       1       2      3       4       5
```

Comment: Thanks! I just looked up what seq does in the above context. What does "dumb 50,15" do? Also trying to understand how the plot works. Is it showing the maximum files created during a certain week? Sorry a little lost

Comment: In `feedgnuplot`, the `--terminal` option requires an argument, which here is `dumb 50,15` -- it means to send output to a [dumb terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals), that's *50 columns* wide, and *14 rows* high.   Try `dumb 30,30` and see what happens.

Comment: The `1` at the bottom is under a bar representing the *5000* or so files created in the most recent week, (the last `7` days), the `2` is the *2500* or so files created in  the week before that, (*7* to *14* days ago), and so on.

Comment: To see a similar graph for each *day* of the last 28 days, try `for f in $(seq 28) ; do find "${dirname}" -type f -ctime $f | wc -l ; done 2> /dev/null |  feedgnuplot  --terminal 'dumb 70,35' --with lines --unset grid --exit` -- give it a minute, since running `find` 28 times is inefficient and slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Looks nice and efficient